# lambda c# function timeout inserting records in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, lambda, timeout

I have to insert a million records into elasticsearch using a lambda function. However, I'm having this timeout issue... The query is taking more than 5 minutes which is the limit to run a lambda. I'm only inserting 800.000 as much. I already increase all the parameters of memory and process in the configuration in lambda.

what solutions do you see?

Comment: You can increase the size of your ES cluster, and you can make parallel bulk requests, or you can process in smaller batches.

Comment: Also you can experiment with the size of your bulk requests, to see what works best with your ES configuration. (I am assuming you're using the bulk api -- if not you should definitely do that.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation just to comment yet so ill give an answer.

Page your records into smaller chunks. and do a lambda on each chunk.

for example if your records are stored in a list you could do something like the following with LinQ.

```
var records = getRecords()

// while there are still records to process
While( records.count > 0){

// get first 100 items in list.
var chunk = records.take(100) 

// remove items from 0 to 99 - so the first 100
records.removeRange(0,99) 

lambdafunction(chunk) // do lambda on chunk
}
```

Comment: You can then further improve performance by passing chunks to async tasks that perform the lambda